# How to retrieve email subject

Tags: php, zend-framework

What is the CORRECT method of the $mail objet that can be used to retrieve an email subject? I know you can set a subject with "setSubject()" but how do I retrieve the subject?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're talking about `Zend_Mail`, see [`Zend_Mail::getSubject()`](http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/1.0/Zend_Mail/Zend_Mail.html#getSubject)

From [SVN](http://framework.zend.com/svn/framework/standard/trunk/library/Zend/Mail.php)

```
/**
 * Returns the encoded subject of the message
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getSubject()
{
    return $this->_subject;
}
```